# Error installing / updating

Tags: installation, upgrading

I am trying to install omega through the UI. But I get this error:

Error installing / updatingFile Transfer failed, reason: Cannot create directory /var/www/drupal/sites/all/themes

How can I bypass this error? I am using vsftpd.

Update: I can connect to my server via a SFTP Client, but I still get the error above.

Comment: Have you tried creating the folder and setting permissions on it?

Comment: There is already a folder with 666 permissions at /sites/all/themes, not no /sites/all/themes/omega

Comment: Are you able to create any dir in sites/all/themes?

Comment: When i am logged in through ssh, yes

Comment: Download and extract omega to your themes folder then ftp the folder.

Comment: I'd recommend using drush if you can though. If your using omega 4 you really want drush to be able to make your sub-theme and to run guard etc..

Comment: I can only get to my users home folder inside fikezilla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17643/discussion-between-dibs-and-user2649805).